# Is there a way to search for answers that recently were awarded bounties?

Tags: feature-request, support, search

I would like to access an answer that recently was awarded a bounty.
Is there a way to efficiently search in SO according to this criterion?

Comment: Shouldn't these question be on "Featured"?

Answer (score 3):

That info isn't accessible from advanced search (there is no 'bounty' flag that I know of).

If you don't mind the data being a week old, you can [use the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/170307/top-200-bounties-by-bounty-amount).

`VoteTypeId = 9` is for closed bounties, and the `votes` table contains a `CreationDate` you can use to find recently ended bounties. The data isn't 100% up to date, but since you are searching for closed bounties, this should help you gather whatever data you are looking for.